# How to Create Multi ssh Tunneling on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I have a running instance on host2 on port p2. I want to access through localhost:p2.

I can ssh to host1 with h1.pem and from host1 i can ssh to host2 with h2.pem.

Comment: Have you set any permissions to allow localhost to access host2 in the EC2 Security Groups settings?

Comment: Let's clarify.  You want to ssh from localhost to h2 (which you cannot directly access) via h1 (which is accessible to you and has access to h2) and you want a TCP tunnel over the ssh session such that connections for localhost:portx are sent over to h2:portx over the end-to-end ssh connection between localhost and h2 (via h1)?

Comment: The irony is not lost on me that the way I described the objective here is not obviously a "clarification" on first reading. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are describing a situation where you have access from localhost (host h0) to host h1 (IP address a.a.a.a), and host h1 has access to host h2 (IP address b.b.b.b), but h0 does not have connectivity to host h2.

You want to connect from h0 to h2 via h1, and establish a TCP tunnel from a port on h0 to a destination port on h2.

I will teach you how to catch this fish, rather than just catching one for you.

First, assuming for a moment that you *did* have direct access from h0 to h2, how would you make an SSH connection?

You would connect like this:

```
ssh -i h2.pem h2user@b.b.b.b
```

...and you could establish a tunnel like this...

```
ssh -i h2.pem h2user@b.b.b.b -L 31337:127.0.0.1:3306
```

This would accept connections on h0 port 31337 and connect it to h2's loopback adapter 127.0.0.1 on port 3306.

I believe is what you want.

But, you don't have direct access to h2, so you need to *proxy* the SSH connection via h1.

From h0, we can connect to h1 like this:

```
ssh -i h1.pem h1user@a.a.a.a
```

So we take that info, and tell SSH that we want to use it to create a `ProxyConnection` to h1, where we'll run the `nc` command, which establishes a remote connection and ties its payload back to stdin and stdout.  SSH will pass the hostname and SSH port of h2 to `nc` running on h1, which will pass back to us on the SSH connection to h1, which we will use to speak SSH to h2. We pass this as `ProxyCommand` to our ssh attempt from h0 to h2.

```
'-o ProxyCommand=ssh -i h1.pem h1user@a.a.a.a nc %h %p'
```

Putting it all together (line breaks for clarity):

```
ssh '-o ProxyCommand=ssh -i h1.pem h1user@a.a.a.a nc %h %p' \
    -i h2.pem \
    h2user@b.b.b.b \ 
    -L 31337:127.0.0.1:3306
```

And there you have it.

Under the hood, h0 makes an ssh connection to h1, where it runs `nc b.b.b.b 22`.  SSH on h0 uses these streams to create a second ssh session to h2 via the connection it already has to h1. The tunnel is negotiated directly with h2 over this connection.

Note that in this scenario, both of the keys h1.pem and h2.pem are on your local machine.  The h2.pem key does not need to be present on h1 at all.

Note also that this has nothing to do with AWS.  It's just standard SSH usage.

---

You can add the `-N` option to the end of the command if you just want to allow the tunnels but you don't want or need to start a shell on h2.

Or if you want a spiffy little monitor showing that your tunnel is still up, you can add this to the very end of the complete `ssh` command shown above.  Be sure to include all of the `'` exactly as shown.

```
'perl -MPOSIX -e '\''$|=1; while(sleep(1)){ print "\e[0GConnected " . POSIX::strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",gmtime)}'\'''
```

This will show a continuously updating message on the console of h0 "Connected YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS" message confirming that your connection is still established end to end.

Comment: It seems like , it should work. I have nt tried yet :) . Just one more clarification: 
**31337:127.0.0.1:3306** here 31337 is local port and 3306 is port on h2 where service is running. so That I can access h2:3306 through local as localhost:31337. Plz clarify and Thanks.

Comment: That's correct.  31337 on localhost connects to 3306 on h2.  The example here was tested, the far-end service was MySQL Server (port 3306) and logging in to the remote service from the local machine using `mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port 31337` worked as expected.

Comment: I tried **ssh '-o ProxyCommand=ssh -i h1.pem  ec2-user@x.x.x.x nc %h %p' \ -i h2.pem \ ec2-user@y.y.y.y \ -L 27017:127.0.0.1:27017** .But I am seeing this error: **_usage: nc [-46DdhklnrStUuvzC] [-i interval] [-p source_port]
   [-s source_ip_address] [-T ToS] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_version]
   [-x proxy_address[:port]] [hostname] [port[s]]
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host_**